# Knob in DigitalOnScreenControl not moving. Why?

Tags: andengine, joystick

I have set up a `DigitalOnScreenControl` in my game but the knob does not move. The base and the knob are drawn on the screen but the latter doesn't move as per the AndEngine example [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/DigitalOnScreenControlExample.java).

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
this.mDigitalOnScreenControl = new DigitalOnScreenControl(300, 300, ResourceManager.getCamera(), ResourceManager.joystickControlBase,
                ResourceManager.joystickControlKnob, 0.1f, ResourceManager.getActivity().getVertexBufferObjectManager(),
                new IOnScreenControlListener() {

            @Override
            public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX,
                    final float pValueY) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "onControlChange");
            }
        });

        final Sprite controlBase = this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase();
        final Sprite knob = this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob();
        controlBase.setAlpha(0.5f);
        controlBase.setOffsetCenter(0, 0);
        controlBase.setScaleCenter(10, 10);
                    controlBase.setScale(1.25f);
        knob.setScale(1.25f);
        this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();
        ResourceManager.getEngine().getScene().attachChild(this.mDigitalOnScreenControl);
```

The `mDigitalOnScreenControl` is a `DigitalOnScreenControl` object defined previously. I use a `ResourceManager` class to obtain texture regions and other game resources such as the camera amongst others. **Note**: Since the base and the knob are drawn, the `ITextureRegions` returned by the `ResourceManager` are valid. When I execute the program, there are no errors in *DDMS*.

The knob just doesn't move. Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you ever call `refreshControlKnobPosition()` in your update code? Is the knob logging `onControlChange`?

Comment: 1) If I put a `Log.v(TAG, "msg")` inside the `onControlChange()`, I get the verbose log at every screen update. This means that `onControlChange()` is being called. 
2) To which update code are you referring? 
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Your main loop, or update loop. I'm not sure if you're required to update the knob position or it's done automatically.

Comment: I proofread my code. The whole code snippet posted (and therefore the `refreshControlKnobPosition()` function) is run in the main loop (`onLoadScene()`). This bug is very strange.

Comment: I even registered an `UpdateHandler` to my Scene and called the `refreshControlKnobPosition` function from the `onUpdate()` function. No luck. By the way, from the `onUpdate()` function, DDMS prints a verbose log message at every screen update.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you try to run the AndEngine example control?

Comment: If I run the example, the knob moves. I spent a couple of hours already trying to figure out where the error may come from. The code base is quite big at the moment to post anything online. Would anybody have any idea where the problem might possibly come from? Camera? or something else? I'm like a detective looking for a bug in a haystack of code here.

Comment: I believe the problem comes on this line: `ResourceManager.getEngine().getScene().attachChild(this.mDigitalOnScreenControl);` Here, I attach the `DigitalOnScreenControl` as a child. In the example, it is added as a `childscene`. The problem is that when I do the same in my code, the joystick appears for a fraction of a second and disappears.

Comment: Ok guys! Thank you so much! The problem was as stated in the previous comment. I didn't know that you should add the `DigitalOnScreenControl` as a `childscene`. To me, this is a bit weird, but that's how things are. What are your comments on this?

Comment: @shailenTJ It's actually pretty sensible as a child scene.  The on screen controls relies on having its own relative coordinate system, so it knows how far you're pushing the knob from a fixed point, regardless of the outside scene coordinates.  I think you should consider posting an answer to your question and accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DigitalOnScreenControl` cannot be attached as a *child* to a scene. It must be attached as a `childscene` to the Engine's current Scene.

```
ResourceManager.getInstance().engine.getScene().setChildScene(joystickControl);
```

In the above code, `joystickControl` extends a `DigitalOnScreenControl` object. After that, depending on how your game is organised, you may need to sort the scenes, in case the `DigitalOnScreenControl` does not appear.

```
ResourceManager.getInstance().engine.getScene().sortChildren();
```

Also, read *Cameron Fredman*'s comment why it is sensible to add the `DigitalOnScreenControl` object as a `childscene`.

Comment: Almost done.  Now click the check mark next to your answer! :)